# python 3 в exe файл с помощью pyinstaller

Tags: python

Если конвертирую консольное приложение, все нормально, если оконное, при запуске exe файла вот такое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> pyinstaller -F -w main.py

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 simple window - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если у кого была такая ошибка, подскажите. Перепробывал почти все. Спасибо.

Comment: Запустите exe'шник в консоли с ключами `--debug` и `-v`. В выводе скорее всего будет причина возникшей проблемы.

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Gornostaev, а у Вас запустилась программа?